# How to separate result inside loop if last value is different

Tags: php, loops, while-loop, echo

I would like to echo all values from my table and separate when different to last one. Like for example

```
table
a
a
b
c
c

result
<div>
a
a
</div>
<div>
b
</div>
<div>
c
c
</div>
```

At the moment I'm compering last echo value to current one but the problem is one of the value is echo inside else statement which cause difficulties to count same values. Just to be clear I'm fetching values from db if value changed it doesn't match the last value but I still need it to echo it otherwise this value will be skipped. I need improve my code so all same values are display in one echo. I hope you understand what I mean.

```
$sql = "select * from bet_slip";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $sql1 = "select * from bet_slip";
    $result1 = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql1 );    
    $row1 = $result1->fetch_assoc();
    $last = $row1["bet_id"];
    echo "<div class='jed'>";
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $prev = $row["bet_id"];
        if($row["bet_id"] == $prev){
            if($prev == $last)
            {       
                //let's say now value change to c so it will be echo inside else and next c will be echo here
                echo $row["bet"]."</br>";
            }
            else
            {   
                echo "</div><div class='trig'></div></br><div class='jed'>else".$row["bet"]."</br>";
            }
        }
        $last = $row["bet_id"]
    }  
}
```

Comment: Why on earth are you doing the query twice?

Comment: I did cause I want it in first if have a match already but yes it doesn't help anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you may have tried to over complicate the issue, unless I misunderstood your question.

```
$sql = "select * from bet_slip";
$result = mysqli_query( $conn, $sql );

$prev = NULL;

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row["bet_id"] != $prev) {
        if ( $prev == NULL) {
            echo "<div class='jed'>";
        } else {
            echo "</div><div class='jed'>";
        }
        $prev = $row["bet_id"];
    }

    echo $row["bet"]."</br>";
}  
echo "</div>";
```